# Why do I get an Unresponsive Script Error on Wygwam fields?

Tags: wygwam

I am working on a site running EE 2.6.1 and wygwam 2.7.1 and I am getting the following error:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let
>   the script continue.
>
> Script:
>   http://www.responsivehomehealth.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:29

I reloaded the wygwam themes folder but the error persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you let the script continue does it ever load?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Hi Brad, I tried many approaches. I clicked continue and I clicked debug and the only thing that works is to click stop.

Comment: Does it occur in different browsers?  Which ones have you tried?

Comment: Hi Brad, it happens in Firefox. Chrome appears to be okay. Thanks.

Comment: Try disabling any Firefox extensions you might have installed?